# When does solution of $Ax = b$ exists, with $x_i \in [0, 1] ~\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose to have the following linear system:
$$Ax = b$$
where $x, b \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$. Suppose also that $A = \{a_{i,j}\}$ has the following properties:

1. $a_{i,j} \geq 0 ~ \forall i,j \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$
2. $a_{i,i} = 0 ~ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$
3. $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} = 1 ~ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$
4. $\det{A} \neq 0$

Now, let's define $S \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ as follows:

$$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : x_i \in [0, 1] ~\forall i\}$$

What are the conditions on $A$ and $b$ that allow to say that $x = A^{-1}b \in S$?

Let's $X$ be the set of solutions when $\det{A} = 0$. What can I say about $X \cap S$?

**-- Addition --**

Here is a results I was able to derive in a particular case.

Suppose that $b_i = \beta \in [0, 1] ~ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ and $\det(A) \neq 0$. Denote with $u$ the vector which all entries are equal to $1$. It turns out that $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_u = 1$. Then.

$$Au = u \Rightarrow u = A^{-1}u$$

Now, consider the unique solution of the system $x = A^{-1}b$.
We know by definition that $b = \beta u$ and then:

$$x = \beta A^{-1}u = \beta u$$

This means that each $x_i = \beta \in [0, 1] ~ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ and hence $x \in S$.

Comment: $A^{-1}$Exists $\iff det(A) \neq 0$

Comment: @Ale I know that... I'm not asking when a unique solution exists...

Comment: This was only a hint to the question $\text{"What are the condition an A and b that allow to say that} x= A^{-1}b$

Comment: @Ale "...to say that $x = A^{-1}b \in S$?"... you forgot $S$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $b\in AS$. And $AS$ is the convex body determined by the images of the vertices of $S$. Is this enough for you?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with $AS$. $A$ is a matrix, while $S$ is a set...

Comment: The image set $AS=\{Ax\vert x\in S\}$.

Comment: Ok, that's right. But can I derive some properties on $A$ and $b$ such that $b \in AS$ without testing if $b \in AS$?

Comment: Testing $b\in AS$ is the obvious way. $AS$ is a hyper-parallelepiped (a deformed hypercube).

Comment: Ok, it seems that $AS \subseteq S$, right?

Comment: Isn't. By convexity, $AS\subset S$ iff all the $A(0,\cdots,0,1,0,\cdots,0)\in AS$. Draw $AS$ for $n=2$ and several choices of $A$ and you will *see* what happens.

Comment: When $n=2$, $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{array}\right]$ is the only feasible one. Then, $Ax = \left[\begin{array}{c}x_2\\x_1\end{array}\right]$. So if $x = \left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right] \in S$, then also $Ax = \left[\begin{array}{c}x_2\\x_1\end{array}\right] \in S$. Right?

Comment: Right, but proving $AS\subset S$ isn't useful. You can have $b\in S$ and $b\notin AS$. And the  phrase about $AS$ of my previous comment is wrong. The good idea is that $AS$ is a known convex body.